# Is there any way to change my play icon to pause , of the current song I am playing, using the Next button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a music player using plain HTML,CSS and Js. It is a simple website to enhance my knowledge about JS in a nutshell. I did most the basic functionalities , in reference to a YouTube Project and implemented my own ideas.

Now the problem is, I want my play button to change into a pause button in my songs section when I click on next to play the next song. The song that is being played has to show the pause button. And the song from where I have clicked next, should show the play button. Any kind of help will be welcomed and I am quite new in this sphere.

The codes and the image of my Website will be attached below :

HTML :

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="flex">
            <li class="logo"><i class="fa-brands fa-napster fa-2xl">Nolae-fy</i></li>


        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container ">

        <div class="songList"></div>
        <h1 class="heading">Enjoy the essence of Hallyu (한류) </h1>
        <div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img  alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="0" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img  alt="">
                <span class="songName">Paul Blanco - 믿어(Believe) (Feat. Crush)</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">3:07 <i id="1" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="2" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="3" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="4" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="5" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="6" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="7" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="songItem flex">
                <img alt="">
                <span class="songName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
                <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">4:19 <i id="8" class="fa-solid songItemPlay  fa-circle-play padding"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="songBanner"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom flex">
        <input type="range" name="range" id="myProgressBar" value="0" min="0" max="100">
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-backward-step" id="previous"></i>
            <i id="masterPlay" class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-circle-play"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-forward-step" id="next"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="songInfo">
            <img src="/img/sakura.gif" alt="" id="gif"><span id="masterSongName">Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream</span>
            

        </div>
        


    </div>
   
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  
</body>
```

JS :

```
console.log("Welcome to Nolae-fy!")
let songIndex = 0
let audioElement = new Audio('song/1.mp3');
let masterPlay = document.getElementById("masterPlay");
let myProgressBar = document.getElementById("myProgressBar");
let gif = document.getElementById("gif");
let songItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItem'));
let miniPlay= Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay'));


let masterSongName = document.getElementById("masterSongName");


let songs = [

    {songName:"Meaningful Stone - A Call from My Dream", filePath:"song/dream.mp3",coverPath:"cover/dream.jpeg"},
    {songName:"Paul Blanco - 믿어(Believe) (Feat. Crush)", filePath:"song/believe.mp3",coverPath:"cover/believe.jpeg"},
    {songName:"Lexie Liu- 佳人 (Kappa Girl)", filePath:"song/kappa.mp3",coverPath:"cover/kappa.jpeg"},
    {songName:"Jay Park - Need to Know", filePath:"song/needtoknow.mp3",coverPath:"cover/needtoknow.jpeg"},
    {songName:"Jungkook - My Time", filePath:"song/mytime.mp3",coverPath:"cover/mytime.jpeg"},
    {songName:"KAI (EXO) - 음 (Mmmh)", filePath:"song/mmmh.mp3",coverPath:"cover/mmmh.jpeg"},
    {songName:"HIGH4 IU- Not Spring, Love, or ..", filePath:"song/spring.mp3",coverPath:"cover/spring.jpeg"},
    {songName:"EXO 엑소 - 'Ko Ko Bop'", filePath:"song/kokobop.mp3",coverPath:"cover/kokobop.jpeg"},
    {songName:"BIBI(비비)- KAZINO", filePath:"song/kazino.mp3",coverPath:"cover/kazino.jpeg"},

]



songItems.forEach((element,i)=>{
    element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = songs[i].coverPath;
    element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0].innerText = songs[i].songName;
    
    // element.getElementsByClassName("timestamp")[0].innerText = audioElement.duration;
})

masterPlay.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if(audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime<=0){
        audioElement.play()
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
    }

    else{
        audioElement.pause()
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
        gif.style.opacity = 0;
    }
})

audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>{
    progress = parseInt((audioElement.currentTime/audioElement.duration)*100)

    // console.log(audioElement.currentTime);
    // console.log(audioElement.duration);
  
    myProgressBar.value = progress
})

myProgressBar.addEventListener("change",()=>{
    audioElement.currentTime = myProgressBar.value * audioElement.duration/100
})

const makeAllPlays = ()=>{
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
        element.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        element.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
    })

    
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("songItemPlay")).forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        makeAllPlays();

        songIndex = parseInt(e.target.id);
        console.log(songIndex);
        e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
        audioElement.src = `song/${songIndex+1}.mp3`;
        masterSongName.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName;
        audioElement.currentTime = 0 ; 
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
    })
})

const makeNewPlays = ()=>{
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
        element.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        element.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
        
       
     }




document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(songIndex>=8){
        songIndex = 0 
    }
    else{
        songIndex += 1
    }
    makeNewPlays();
   
    
   
    audioElement.src = `song/${songIndex+1}.mp3`;
    masterSongName.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName;
    
    audioElement.currentTime = 0 ; 
    audioElement.play();
    masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
    masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
    gif.style.opacity = 1;


})


document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(songIndex<=0){
        songIndex = 0 
    }
    else{
        songIndex -= 1
    }
    makeNewPlays();
    audioElement.src = `song/${songIndex+1}.mp3`;
    masterSongName.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName;
    audioElement.currentTime = 0 ; 
    audioElement.play();

    masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
    masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
    gif.style.opacity = 1;

    
})
```

[The image of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgGqV.jpg)

I tried various implementations but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: It's hard to say what exactly to try without knowing what you've already tried, and what happened after that. My first instinct would be to change the source of the play image to the source of the pause image. I'm sure you could get more help if you provided more information!

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. The thing if you check the image of my website, which I have attached, there are capsules with the song name and a play button. All I want is whenever, I have clicked the next button or previous , I want this play button to change into a pause button, of the song that is being currently played. About the main play button, which is at the bottom, I have already derived the logic to alternate between play and pause, while a song is being played.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions would work in this situation:

**1. Change the `src` attribute of an image from the "play" image file to the "pause" image file.**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let target = document.getElementById("image");

    target.addEventListener("click", () => {
        target.setAttribute("src", "other_image.jpg");
    });
});
```

You could edit the event listener so it toggles between the different source attribute values.

**2. Load BOTH images into the DOM, and toggle their visibilty**

[This article on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) offers a great tutorial of toggling the visibility of an element. You could just have two elements and next to each other, but only one visible at any given time, and toggle that value.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. The thing if you check the image of my website, which I have attached, there are capsules with the song name and a play button. All I want is whenever, I have clicked the next button or previous , I want this play button to change into a pause button, of the song that is being currently played. About the main play button, which is at the bottom, I have already derived the logic to alternate between play and pause, while a song is being played. Thank you so much for the suggestion anyways. I will work on it.